# After updating php, server no longer accesses "Sites" folder

Tags: php, macos, apache

I was following a tutorial just about how to set up php on Mac. I had it set up to the point where I could load my php file which consists only of

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

and is named "my_phpinfo.php." It was displaying fine in my browser via an apache server. But after updating to the latest version of apache like the next step of the tutorial told me to, my browser no longer seems able to access  the php file. And as I was typing this message out, it doesn't even seem to be able to access my user configuration (localhost/~*myusername*). Does this make sense? Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: This question is more related to `apache` than `php`. Perhaps it is your permissions. You can get more info in the apache logs.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the tutorial and what the failing step is?

Comment: @Fotis it's a lynda learning course, so I can link to it but I don't know if you can access it. https://www.lynda.com/MySQL-tutorials/Upgrading-PHP/119003/136922-4.html The video before this one was fine, but after the upgrade it stopped working.

Comment: @jeepersmcface sorry I can't access it. But I'm guessing that the variable `UserDir` might have been overridden by the upgrade. Can you check your apache config to see what the value of `UserDir` is and update according to this documentation page? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html

Comment: @Folis I couldn't find the `UserDir` variable. Should it be in the `httpd.conf` file? I added it to the `<Directory>` part of the httpd.conf and then pointed it to my directory and still no cigar.

I found this which is essentially all that I have done so far to get this to work (at least until it gets to "Override .htaccess"): 

https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/